# C - print file using system calls?

Tags: c, command-line

I'm trying to get aquainted with system calls and C. I'm trying to read a file and write all the contents to the command line. I'm trying

```
int handle = open("./test.txt", O_RDONLY, O_TEXT);
char buf[1];
lseek(handle, 0, SEEK_SET);
while (0 != read(handle, buf, 1)) {
        printf(*buf);
}
```

This ALMOST works, except that it adds some gibberish characters after each character read from the file. For example if the file contains `asd asd` this writes `a:_s:_d:_ :_a:_s:_d` to the console. Any idea why? How can I fix it?

Comment: `printf(*buf);`, no, not at all.

Comment: try `putchar(*buf);`.

Comment: Warnings, where are they?

Comment: if you really want printf, then `printf( "%c", buf[0] )` would work too.

Answer (score 2):

Every string has to end with the `\0` (null) character.

So try to make your buffer size 2, and just before `printf` do `buf[1] = '\0';`

In general when you read `wcnt (type ssize_t)` number of chars you do `buf[wcnt] = '\0';`

Also your printf is not syntaxed <s>correctly</s> safely!
`printf("%s", buf);`

Edit: As mentioned in other answers and comments (I will not add it since I did not propose it first), you can just print a char in this case.

Comment: If the OP did what you say, it's legal to call `printf(buf)` but very unsafe, because `buf` could contain a specifier and then Undefined Behavior would occur. Therefore, the safe thing to do is  `printf("%s", buf);` or `printf("%c", *buf);` without the need to `'\0'` terminate the `buf`.

Comment: Or `puts(buf)`.

Comment: There's no need to make it a *string* at all here. You don't need a *marker* (null terminator) when you know there's just only one char is read at most ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You code should produce warnings on most modern compilers. Because `printf()` doesn't accept a *char*. Since you are reading the file char by char, you can instead use `putchar()` to print on the stdout.

```
while (read(handle, buf, 1) == 1) {
    putchar(buf[0]);
}
```

Comment: @AndrewHenle I didn't notice it as I copied from OP. Fixed now.